# How the apparmor works?

Tags: apparmor

How to use apparmor to confine reading one file if there are two files?
I have used autodep, enforce, and complain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a an extremely large topic but basically apparmor uses text files called profiles a set of predefined rules for processes.  Apparmor has access to files, network, mount, unmount, dbus,  ptrace, signal and sockets to monitor and control these process.  Basically if a process tries to break one of these rules it can be either restricted or killed along with logging everything.  Below is a link that will explain this in much better detail.

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/beginning-apparmor-profile-development#1-overview